# How did Superman return from the Phantom Zone?

Tags: dc, superman, superman-brainiac-attacks

In *Superman: Brainiac Attacks* telefilm, Superman went to Phantom Zone to obtain an element to cure Lois Lane from Kryptonite poisoning. After obtaining the element, he did return to Metropolis to save Lois & stop Brainiac.

AFAIK, portal can't be opened from inside the Phantom Zone. How did Superman return from the Phantom Zone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer:

**It is never explained in detail how Superman returns to our universe from the Phantom Zone. Perhaps that information was cut from the final film production. Given the less than stellar quality of the film, it would not surprise me to be just a general oversight.**

### A bit more detail:

Superman: Brainiac Attacks is one of those cringe-worthy productions that seems to find the worst elements of the Superman Adventures universe and put them into a movie.

One of the major inconsistencies with the movie was its portrayal of the Phantom Zone.

“The Phantom Zone, discovered by one of Krypton’s greatest scientist, Jor-El, is a world of boundless twilight, a stopping place between being and nothingness… a dimension without dimensions, without horizons, without sensations, without hope. Its denizens are mere impressions of their former selves, astral bodies hovering in mist, conversing by though… for though is not only communication, but the sum of existence in this endless nowhere.”

[image]

Inside the Zone, instead of the mist-like or ghost-like existence previously described, we see an entirely different universe, more like the Marvel Universe's [Negative Zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_Zone), complete with native appearing creatures.

[image]

- The Zone was able to be entered using the computer inside of the Fortress of Solitude. We had see the previous Superman Adventures Phantom Zone projector and it was an ugly and ungainly thing. (but maybe the producers of this movie didn't know that, or perhaps Kal-El kept the tiny, pocket-sized version of the device in his fortress.
- HIs computer created a portal by which Superman entered the Zone and the computer hinted/implied he would be able to leave the zone by navigating back to the same point.
- This is inconsistent with any other portrayal of the Phantom Zone since the only way to leave prior to this was through the use of the Phantom Zone Ray, which allowed a person to resync with our universe.
- With all this at our fingertips, we are forced to assume he left the zone the same way he entered, perhaps with a device which triggered the standing Zone portal exactly where it was when his fortress was destroyed. Presumably, it was a one trip ticket and no villains will be using it to escape in the future.

[image]